# Dashboard Title alignment?

Tags: visualforce, charts

below image i marked with red color i need to align the title on center.please can anyone help me out

**Vf page:**

```
<apex:page controller="ChartController2" >

<apex:pageblock  title="Members and their Years of experience" mode="maindetail" >

    <apex:chart height="400" width="400" data="{!months}" colorSet="#FFFF00,#FFFF00,#FFFF00,#9ACD32,#9ACD32" >
        <apex:axis type="Numeric" position="left" fields="volume" title="Record Count" />
        <apex:axis type="Category" position="bottom" fields="year" title="Year" />

       <apex:barSeries  orientation="vertical" axis="left" xField="year" yField="volume" colorsProgressWithinSeries="true"  title="Deliveries By Year" />

              </apex:chart>    
 </apex:pageblock>

</apex:page>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you cannot directly use the style attribute on pageblock element.. but you can change the existing style using this

```
<style>
.pbTitle{
text-align : center;
}
</style>
```

add this style to your page and the text on the page block title should be center aligned.